# How can I display only the 1st line when I have multiple tables involved?

Tags: sql, database

```
SELECT A.numeClient, A.CNP, A.Adresa, count(B.Eveniment) AS NR_EVE,B.Agent 
FROM client A , eveniment B
WHERE A.CNP=B.CNP --AND ROWNUM =1
GROUP BY A.numeClient, A.CNP, A.Adresa,B.Agent
ORDER BY count(B.Eveniment) desc --LIMIT 1;
```

I want to display the client with the highest amount of events from table eveniment B and the rest of the info. I tried with rownum, but it doesn't work. Also tried with LIMIT 1, but that is out of the window since I need to use Oracle SQL 9. Is there any way around ? I tried using multiple Select, but I don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to solve it.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT A.numeClient, A.CNP, A.Adresa, count(B.Eveniment) AS NR_EVE,B.Agent 
        FROM client A , eveniment B
        WHERE A.CNP=B.CNP --AND ROWNUM BETWEEN 1 AND 2
        GROUP BY A.numeClient, A.CNP, A.Adresa,B.Agent
        ORDER BY count(B.Eveniment) desc )
WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```